# MongoDB - Return dynamic values in the project stage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I wanted to structure my response object in the project stage of aggregation. But I am facing a problem in concatenating a string with another key value.

Here is my aggregation return result:

```
[
  {
    "total_price": 8.92,
    "paymentStatus": "Paid",
    "refundedAmount": 5
  },
  {
    "total_price": 20.92,
    "paymentStatus": "Paid",
    "refundedAmount": 15
  }
]
```

But I want to return the result as the structure of:

```
[
  {
    "total_price": 8.92,
    "paymentStatus": "Paid",
    "refundedAmount": 5,
    "description": "Refunded 5"
  },
  {
    "total_price": 20.92,
    "paymentStatus": "Paid",
    "refundedAmount": 15,
    "description": "Refunded 15"
  }
]
```

Here totalPrice, paymentStatus and refundedAmount are available in database.
I want to add a key called description while project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `$concat` operator and convert `refundedAmount` to string.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      total_price: 1,
      paymentStatus: 1,
      refundedAmount: 1,
      description: {
        $concat: [
          "Refunded ",
          {
            $toString: "$refundedAmount"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B0wRKBc0sjj)